# "Address already in use" DataramSocket in receive datagram

Tags: java, sockets, udp, datagram

I have a problem (obviously). I am noob in UDP in java sorry.

I am making an application for sending and receive UDP datagrams.The idea to run 2 times the same program and send and receive packets, which I am doing with threads. The problem , receibve this program always gives me the same message.

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

It has to do with the port that I try to open in use, but I do so with any port you try, 80, 8080, 12345.
Even watch online command ports were free, but if you tell me who are equally busy.

```
netstat -a
```

The code is :

Sender

```
class envioNodo extends Thread {
byte[] tablaEnca = new byte[10000];
int port = 0;
int puertoVecino = 0;
String IP_envio = "" , IP_emisor ="";
public envioNodo(String tE , String IP , int puerto , String IP_e) {
    port = puerto;
    IP_envio = IP;
    IP_emisor = IP_e;
    System.out.println("Se enviará el vector de distancias a la IP "+ IP_envio +" con puerto "+ port);
}
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Se ejecuta el envio de paquetes del nodo");
    try {
        DatagramSocket dS = new DatagramSocket(); // null //Sin null envia los datos por un puerto cualquiera udp

        dS.setReuseAddress(true);

        DatagramPacket dP = null;
            try {
                dP = new DatagramPacket(tablaEnca , tablaEnca.length, InetAddress.getByName(IP_envio)  , port); 
                dS.send(dP);
                System.out.println("Paquete enviado");

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                dS.send(dP);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            dS.close();

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Receive

```
class recepcionNodos extends Thread {
int port = 0;
String vD_rN ;
byte[] buff = new byte[10000];
DatagramPacket dP = null;
DatagramSocket dS = null;
public recepcionNodos(int puerto){
    port = puerto;
    System.out.println("Inicio del hilo de espera de respueta");
    System.out.println("El puerto por el que se escuchara es el "+ port);
}
public void run(){
    do{
        try {
            System.out.println("Comienzo recepcion");
            port++;
            dS = new DatagramSocket(port);
            dP = new DatagramPacket(buff,buff.length);
            System.out.println("Espera en el receive");
            dS.receive(dP);
            vD_rN = new String(dP.getData()).substring(0,dP.getLength());
            System.out.println("String recibido.");
            System.out.print(vD_rN);
            System.out.println("Paquete recibido!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error en recepcion del paquete!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }while(true);
}
```

Whit DatagramSocket and DatagramPacket = null.

I Start whit send *DatagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();* In this position the constructor get first port can send datagram , ¿But receive i dont know , How do can't receive the packets UDP?

Edit : i have 2 interfaces 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2 and run one program en one interface whit :

```
Sudo ip addr add
```

Solution :

```
class recepcionNodos extends Thread {
    int port = 0 , aux = 0;
    String vD_rN ;
    byte[] buff = new byte[10000];
    DatagramPacket dP = null;
    DatagramSocket dS = null;
    public recepcionNodos(int puerto){
        port = puerto;
        System.out.println("Inicio del hilo de espera de respueta");
        System.out.println("El puerto por el que se escuchara es el "+ port);
    }
    public void run(){
        do{
            try {
                System.out.println("Comienzo recepcion");
                port++;
                dS = new DatagramSocket(port);

                dP = new DatagramPacket(buff,buff.length);
                System.out.println("Espera en el receive");
                dS.receive(dP);
                vD_rN = new String(dP.getData()).substring(0,dP.getLength());
                System.out.println("String recibido.");
                System.out.print(vD_rN);
                System.out.println("Paquete recibido!");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error en recepcion del paquete!");
                e.printStackTrace();
                e.printStackTrace();
                Rip r = new Rip();
                port = Rip.generarPuerto(); // and this function
                System.out.println(port);
                if(aux != 0)
                 System.exit(1);
                aux++;

            }

        }while(true);
    }
```

This is :

```
public static int generarPuerto() {
        int aux = 0;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Random r = new Random();
        r.setSeed(r.nextLong());
        aux = r.nextInt(49151 - 1024 - 1) + 1024;
        return aux;
}
```

My problem is :

2 interfaces :

```
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
```

And run in a aplication whit 1 IP and other whit other IP , but i think the ports is independents . I use this function and no broblem , but now have the problem i can't receive mensage.

PD : And any whit very much experience or reputation wants to reform the post is free.
PD2 : Sorry , very long post and very much edits.
PD3 : Very much thx for help , this forum is the best for problems programming.

Comment: Running the same program twice at the same time? And it includes both sender and receiver? It's probably running the code that opens the same port twice.

Comment: And your code is not showing that you are binding the socket to any particular local address. If your code is not what you showed, please update the code in the question.

Comment: @RealSkeptic update , but i run with command line : java project 10.0.0.1 , no get variable in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your port. Check your port of Server code. If you have two Server running on the same system when same port numbers the second server will never start because it is already in use by the first Server.

Solution: Use two different port numbers in both Server. For example 7070 for first and 7080 for second server program.

Comment: I use 3 interfaces :  sender 10.0.0.1: XXXX , receiver 10.0.0.1:8080 and second interface sender 10.0.0.2:XXXXX , receiver 10.0.0.2:8080 , I should have no problem whit port.

Comment: Are you running both server and client in same computer?

Comment: yep , but diferent interfaces IP , therefore each has its ports.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the socket before you open another one.
For example:

```
do{
    try {
        //Create a new socket.
        dS = new DatagramSocket(port);
        dP = new DatagramPacket(buff,buff.length);
        dS.receive(dP);
        vD_rN = new String(dP.getData()).substring(0,dP.getLength());
        System.out.println(vD_rN);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
       //Close the socket and free the port after the message was received.
       if (dS != null) {
           dS.close();
       }
    }
}while(true);
```

Comment: @AnubianNoob yes they can because this is a loop and a new socket which listens to the same port is created once the previous one was closed.

Comment: Once the socket closes the second iteration of the loop will cause an exception. You can't read from or write to a closed socket.

Comment: @AnubianNoob I've tested this and it works. This code doesn't reuse the closed socket, it created a new one. This is a `do{}while(true)` loop if you haven't notice.

Comment: Oh my bad, I missed that line. But you still both instances of the program won't be able to have their socket up to read or write _at the same time_. While one is up, the other one will throw an exception which will be squelched by the `catch`, until the running one closes the socket, at which point this one can initialize its socket. The programs will still not be able to communicate, and in any case you should not be reinitializing a socket every loop.

Comment: Oh sorry, the problem is the other program won't be able to bind its socket and send while this socket is waiting for a response.

Comment: This will work as long as he executes the sender code before the receiver since the receiver will close the program (`System.exit(1)`) if the port is already in use. If he does that he will have 2 instances, the receiver which will always be running and the sender which will close as soon as it sends the package.

Comment: In do{}while(true) all running the receiver thread , and other comment , dS.receive(dP) , wait a new datagrams.

Answer (score 0):

You can only bind one socket to a port at a time.

Since you're running the program twice locally, both sockets are trying to bind to the same port.

There are a couple of possible fixes:

1. Have two separate programs on different ports.
2. Have an easy way to change the port between runs.
3. Automatically change the port if the original port is in use.

I'd suggest the last option. If you catch that error, try binding to a secondary port. When you try to send a packet, send it to both sockets. That'd be a quick and easy solution.

Comment: I run program in diferents interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

"Address already bind exception", You can make only one socket to run on a particular port. As both sender and receiver are in same program you can use different ports for sender and receiver and try it.